# How can I search question with two tags?

Tags: support, tags, questions

Searching with `[c#][.net]` results that question with both tags. So, it is `and` condition when searching that way.

But I wanna know how to search with `or` condition so that the resulting questions have one or both of tags?

Comment: hmm.. did you use the new questions page or the search box? The earlier is `or`-ing by default: http://stackoverflow.com/?tags=c%23%20.net

Comment: I'm using search box, how do one achieve that or-ing? By writing manually?

Comment: I checked with the search box and I just wrote `[c#][.net]` and got the expected results. With the new questions page you can use the "custom tags" filter

Comment: aah, no, that doesn't work, it's and-ing. And your link doesn't work for me

Comment: could you please add `&mode=any` to the end of the url?

Comment: I couldn't find where they explain or show "custom tags". could you give me a link

Comment: It seems like `[c#] OR [.net]` works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quickly checking the ["extended advanced search help"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) reveals there actually is an or-operator.

soo.. `[c#] or [.net]` should work just fine

Comment: It gets funny when restricting that , though, like it must be about [office-interop]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+office-interop+or+.net+office-interop (One *can* ask for them, but only by hacking the url directly)